# Understanding $.Deferred() sequencies and $.fn.pipe()

Tags: jquery, sequence, pipe, deferred

I am stuck in this code:

```
reload: function() {
            var self = this;
            $.when(self.unload()).then(function() {
                self.load();
            });
        },
load: function() {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: self.options.url,
                success: function(data) {
                    $.Deferred(
                        function(dfr) {
                            $.each(data, function() {
                                var div = $('<div></div>')
                                    .addClass('nw-item')
                                    .html('newsitem.ejs', this)
                                    .hide()
                                    .appendTo(self.element);
                                dfr = dfr.pipe(function() {
                                    return div.slideDown(self.options.speed);
                                });
                            });
                        }).resolve();
                }
            })
        },
unload: function() {
            var items = this.element.children('.nw-item').reverse(),
                self = this,
                udfd = $.Deferred(
                    function(dfr) {
                        $.each(items, function() {
                            var div = $(this);
                            dfr = dfr.pipe(function() {
                                return div.slideUp(self.options.speed);
                            });
                        });
                    }).resolve();
            return udfd;
        }
```

in "reload" I need to start "load" sequence after "unload" sequence is completed, but it starts right after first iteration of "unload" sequence element becomes hidden. Help me please, I'm stuck(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but try this:

```
unload: function() {
    var items = this.element.children('.nw-item').reverse();
    var self = this;
    var udfd = $.Deferred();
    var chain;
    $.each(items, function() {
        chain = udfd.pipe(function() {
            return $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
                div.slideUp(self.options.speed, function() {
                    // callback function gets executed when slideUp is done
                    deferred.resolve();
                });                
            }).promise();
        });
    });
    chain.done(function() {
        udfd.resolve();
    });
    return udfd.promise();
}
```

Since your jQuery.slideUp function is asynchronous BUT does not return an Deferred Object like e.g. jQuery.ajax you have to manually return a Deferred/promise. When your chain of piped functions is done it resolves the main Deferred. Don't forget to return a promise for the main Deferred.

Like I said, no guarantee but you could give it a try!